# How to display hidden div on anchor onclick with no href using Javascript within PHP code?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I do not want my page to reload so I am not using PHP function and $GET to display a div in PHP.

I am trying to echo a table with td containing an anchor link which when onclicked will display the hidden div.

Here is the PHP code :

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr><td><a href='javascript:;' onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'detailsDiv\').style.display=\'block\'\">View Details</a></td></tr></table>";

 echo "<div id='detailsDiv' style='display: none;'>";
 echo "<h1>Hello World!!</h1>";
 echo "</div>";
 ?>
```

Also getting this error:

```
 SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script
```

Comment: Remove the `href` attribute from the anchor. It isn't needed.

Comment: Getting "SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script"

Comment: Remove `href='javascript:;'` and change `onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'detailsDiv\').style.display=\'block\'\"` to `onclick=\"document.getElementById('detailsDiv').style.display='block'\"`

Answer (score 3):

Your code throws an error, if you want a more cleaner way, try:

```
<script>
    function hideDiv() {
        document.getElementById("detailsDiv").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
<?php
    echo "<table><tr><td><a href='#' onclick='hideDiv();'>View Details</a></td></tr></table>";

    echo "<div id='detailsDiv' style='display: none;'>";
    echo "<h1>Hello World!!</h1>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Getting "SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script"

Comment: I tested this before I posted my answer. Hmm what seems to be your problem? You can try https://jsfiddle.net/